# What is the equivalent of Bluebird Promise.finally in native ES6 promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Bluebird offers a [`finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) method that is being called whatever happens in your promise chain. I find it very handy for cleaning purposes (like unlocking a resource, hiding a loader, ...)

Is there an equivalent in ES6 native promises?

Comment: ECMAScript Proposal (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally) and v8's flag (node --harmony_promise_finally app.js) exist.

Comment: You can try the `when` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/when

Answer (score 280):

As of February 7, 2018

Chrome 63+, Firefox 58+, and Opera 50+ support [`Promise.finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally).

In Node.js 8.1.4+ (V8 5.8+), the feature is available behind the flag [`--harmony-promise-finally`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/18ad0f13afeaabff4e035fddd9edc3d319152160).

The [Promise.prototype.finally ECMAScript Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally) is currently in [stage 3](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) of the TC39 process.

In the meantime to have promise.finally functionality in all browsers; **you can add an additional `then()` after the `catch()` to always invoke that callback**.

Example:

```
myES6Promise.then(() => console.log('Resolved'))
            .catch(() => console.log('Failed'))
            .then(() => console.log('Always run this'));
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9frfjcsg/**

Or you can extend the prototype to include a `finally()` method (not recommended):

```
Promise.prototype.finally = function(cb) {
    const res = () => this;
    const fin = () => Promise.resolve(cb()).then(res);
    return this.then(fin, fin);
};
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c67a6ss0/1/**

There's also the [Promise.prototype.finally](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.prototype.finally) shim library.

Comment: It's worth mentioning this .catch() will catch not only original Promise's failure, but also all errors thrown in original .then() handler. So it's easy to accidentally suppress some error message with this code.

Comment: if (Promise.prototype.finally == undefined) {
      Promise.prototype.finally = function (callback) {
        return this.then(function (result) {
          return Promise.resolve(callback()).then(function () {
            return result;
          });
        }, function (error) {
          return Promise.resolve(callback()).then(function () {
            throw error;
          });
        });
      };
    }

Comment: Why is the `prototype.finally` approach not recommended?

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how `finally` should receive a parameter as state no matter the promise resolve/reject 
`Promise.prototype.finally = function(cb) {
  const res = () => this
  const fin = (value) => Promise.resolve(cb(value)).then(res)
  return this.then(fin, fin)`

Comment: @JanHommes it is never recommended to extend prototypes with custom methods. When the spec decides to add a native implementation of `.finally()` or whatever method you're adding to the prototype, you'd end up with a broken implementation and your app may stop working on newer browsers.

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo Extending prototypes behind a feature check is fine. This is commonly done to polyfill newer features wherever they're not present.