# Show Apollo mutation error to user in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I am using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) with [Vue-Apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo) and initiating a User mutation to sign in a user. I am using the graph.cool service.

I have a request pipeline function setup to catch some errors, like an invalid email.

When the request is made with bad / invalid input, my error `catch()` fires (as expected) and in the network tab I can see the JSON for the custom errors messages. But how do I access these errors / response from within the catch if an error is triggered from graph.cool?

**Example:**

```
signin () {
  const email = this.email
  const password = this.password

  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: signinMutation,
    variables: {
      email,
      password
    }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // This never fires on an error, so I can't 
    // show the user the errors in the network repsonse.
    console.log(data) 
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Error in this part fires in the console 
    // but I'm unable to show the JSON response 
    // errors because the 'then()' above doesn't execute.
    console.error(error)
  })
}
```

I get the following error for an unrecognised user:

> Error: GraphQL error: No user found with that information
>       at new ApolloError (eval at  (app.js:956), :34:28)
>       at eval (eval at  (app.js:1353), :139:33)
>       at

Any idea how to show the errors in the response from within the `catch()`?

I can literally see the errors I want to show to the user in the response on the network tab here:

[image]

...but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I think you can add another `.then` after the `.catch`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999072/what-is-the-equivalent-of-bluebird-promise-finally-in-native-es6-promises

Comment: Whilst that's true, I can't get hold of the 'data' in the actual response itself. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it looks as though I was handling this the wrong way by barking up the wrong tree.

The key to the answer was examining the error from the `.catch()` with `console.dir(error)`. This revealed some useful keys...namely:

```
error.graphQLErrors[0]
```

So all in all, the corrected code looks like this:

```
signin () {
  const email = this.email
  const password = this.password

  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: signinMutation,
    variables: {
      email,
      password
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(graphQLErrorMessages(error))
  })
}
```

The `graphQLErrorMessages()` function is a helper I wrote, so that I can reuse this in other `.catch()` blocks:

```
function graphQLErrorMessages (errorsFromCatch) {
  const errors = errorsFromCatch.graphQLErrors[0]
  const messages = []

  if (errors.hasOwnProperty('functionError')) {
    const customErrors = JSON.parse(errors.functionError)
    messages.push(...customErrors.errors)
  } else {
    messages.push(errors.message)
  }

  return messages
}
```

It returns an array of error messages (which is what I needed) but you could format this any way you like.

It might be a little https://graph.cool specific in its logic (I'm not so  sure), but I hope this ends up helping someone also stuck in a similar situation!

Comment: The Graphcool specific part is the property `functionError`, that only gets returned [in a Graphcool Function](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/functions/error-handling-quawa7aed0/) when you want to return an error. Also, if the `catch` is active, there is no guarantee that `graphQLErrors` has an item. So you should first check if `graphQLErrors.length > 0`.

Comment: This is crazy that the official docs don't even mention this graphql error field at all! Took me too long to find this

Answer (score -1):

I may be misunderstanding your question so please comment and correct me if I am but it looks like you may be having trouble with Promises more than with Vue or GraphQL.

Just like in a `try...catch` statement, once you catch an error, your program will continue to execute unless you re-throw the error. For example:

**This Catches**

```
try { 
  codeThatThrowsAnError();
} catch(e) {
  // Do Nothing
}
```

**This re-throws**

```
try { 
  codeThatThrowsAnError();
} catch(e) {
  throw new Error("Err 135: I failed")
}
```

Similarly, in Promise land, you can either catch the error and move like you have in your example, or you can re-throw. What you may be missing is that anything you return from a catch statement will be used in the next `then`. For example:

```
somethingReturningAFailedPromise()
  .then(doWork)
  .catch((err) => {
    return "I'm a New Value"
  })
  .then(console.log)

//=> "I'm a New Value"
```

It sounds to me like what you need is a data function that is more resilient to failure like the following:

```
const getUserProfile = (id) => {
  return fetchUserData(id)
    .catch((err) => {
      logError(err);
      return {};
    })
}
```