# What is the meaning of 'catch(...)' with no '{...}' block following it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see a piece of code similar to the one below in some `npm` package:

```
this.func(callback).then(function() {
  ...
  return x;
}).then(function() {
  ...
  return y;
}).then(function() {
  ...
  return z;
}).then(function() {
  mocha.run(function(failures) {
    ...
    callback(failures);
  });
}).catch(callback);
```

Questions:

1. What is the meaning of this `catch(callback)` with no `{...}` block following it?
2. I would like to add a `finally` clause to execute the `callback`, but every syntax that I'm trying seems to fail:

- `.catch(callback).finally(callback);`
- `.catch(callback).finally(callback());`
- `.catch(callback).finally{callback()};`
- `.catch(callback).finally(){callback()};`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: A promise's `catch` accepts a function as an argument, that's all. `Promise.prototype.finally()` is *very* new.

Comment: @Teemu: Thank you. How can I add `finally` in the same manner?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, then and catch refer to Promise's prototype and not to the native catch implementation. Check this example to understand it better:

```
let doSomething = () {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try { 
         reject(); 
       } catch(e) {
         reject(); 
        } finally {
          console.log('done');
        }
   });
}

doSomething().then(() => {}).catch(() => {});
```

Note that anything you'd do, catch will be called.

Comment: I think you probably meant `try { resolve(); }`. Also, how can I do `finally` here?

Comment: No, I did it reject, to show that catch can also be called from within try. Also, updated my answer on how you could do finally.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `catch` function refers to your `callback` function which you are passing in `catch` block

```
//first case
function callback(){}

catch(callback);
//second case 
catch(function(){})
```

Both case will work

and for `finally` It is still lacking browser support, you can check here at bottom of this page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

and check this for how to do `finally` in alternative way.

[what is the equivalent of bluebird Promise.finally in native ES6 promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999072/what-is-the-equivalent-of-bluebird-promise-finally-in-native-es6-promises)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.
For more detail on promise: [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

```
doSomething(()=>{//do something})
.then(()=>{})
.catch((error)=> { console.log(error); })
.finally(()=> { //finally block here });
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: The [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) calls the function passed in the `catch` whenever a promise gets "[rejected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)". So consider the following code:

```
// method 1: define the callback function
var callback = function(error){
    console.error(error); // console the error
};
this.func.then(...).catch(callback);

// method 2: pass the function assigned to "callback" variable itself 

this.func.then(...).catch(function(error){
    console.error(error); // console the error
});
```

You are just telling the promise returned by the above (in your code) function call(s) that:
"Hey, whenever you fail to do the task, call this function `callback` that I (or someone else) have defined."

Question 2: The first method in your list of four methods should work.